# rubber failing to complete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, rubber

I've got rubber working and am using `rubber vulcanize complete_unicorn_nginx_postgresql`.  Running `cap rubber:create_staging` fails after getting pretty far through the process.  Here is the output of the failing portion:

```
* executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: '  bash -l /tmp/create_master_db"
servers: ["web-staging.site.com"]
[web-staging.site.com] executing command
** [out :: web-staging.site.com] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "-"
** [out :: web-staging.site.com] LINE 1: CREATE USER my-website WITH NOSUPERUSER CREATEDB NOCREATE...
** [out :: web-staging.site.com] ^
command finished in 625ms
failed: "/bin/bash -l -c 'sudo -p '\\''sudo password: '\\''  bash -l /tmp/create_master_db'" on web-staging.site.com
```

At this point, I'm at a loss on what to look at/modify to get rubber to successfully deploy to the ec2 instance and bring up the rails app for me to see.  Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

We'll this one had nothing to do with Rubber... the app name had a dash in it (site-x), and apparently rubber created a postgres user with the same name (site-x).  So it was gumming up the works.